# In Browser's Dev tool,How can I know one file is requested by which file from the server?

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-chrome-devtools

for example:
How can I know this file is requested by which file from the server?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `x` next to the Headers tab? Click it and you should be presented with a table. One of the columns is "Initiator". That's the resource that requested the resource under "Name".

[Image for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69vTl.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can also hold shift while hovering over a resource to view its initiator and any of its dependencies. The initiator is green, dependencies are red.

[image]

Comment: Awesome.Thank you.But if there are hundreds of files ,How can I see the dependencies or initiator in the bottom.

Comment: This feature probably won't be useful in that scenario. You could try filtering to reduce the number of files that are displayed.